# How to pass Boolean value to the controls React.Js

Tags: reactjs, html5-video

How to pass Boolean value to the controls React.Js

class App extends React.Component {

```
constructor(props) {

  **// Calling super class constructor**
  super(props);
    
  **// Creating state**
  this.state ={
    video.controls= false

  }
  
}
 
render() {
    return (
    
        <div className= "container">
            <video controls>
            <source src="http://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/gtv-videos-bucket/sample/BigBuckBunny.mp4" type="video/mp4"></source>
            <p>Your browser doesn't support HTML5 video.</p>
            </video>
        </div>
    );
} }
```

export default App;

Answer (score 0):

You have to pass the state value into the `<video>` tag. To do it, you need to apply two changes in your code:

The first one, and as a suggestion, is to not create a nested object directly in your state, if you want to add a nested object I would definitely recommend you to use the format of: `video: { controls: false }` insead of your current `video.controls = false` value. So it would end being something like this:

```
this.state = {
  videoControls: false
}
```

And then you could use the state into the tag by wrapping it into object keys `{}`:

```
<video controls={this.state.videoControls}>
  {/* Your code comes here... */}
</video>
```